# What is a good workout logger that help me keep track of my training progress?

Tags: exercise

I'm looking for a logger for my exercises, where I can record reps, see progress, etc. I am into weightlifting [*or write here whatever you are doing*] but I would like to be able to record my cardio progress and others, too.

Is there any such program, online site, smartphone app?

Comment: Why did this question collect a couple of downvotes?

Comment: @Mephisto because the user should have known better, asking for "the best something" always triggers the red warning lamp for the close reason below. He doesn't even tell his goals or preferences. And then there simply is "lack of research effort".

Comment: @Infomaficker, I understand. Since I find the question interesting, I have proposed an edit to take the "best something" away and give some additional details (though I am afraid this is a non-registered user that will probably never appear again) that

Comment: I accepted that edit, though I'm afraid it didn't change much, and it's still subjective.

Answer (score 2):

There are some nice Android applications for free, like [Lifting Log](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.kndy.liftinglog&hl=en) and [Fit77](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.katsoftwarellc.liftlog&hl=en) for general weight training; [LiftBig](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=liftbig.lb.sources&hl=en_GB) specifically for SL5x5, or [HIIT](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ihunda.android.hiit&hl=en), that will additionally help you with your cardio.

Also, [here, in EXRX](http://www.exrx.net/WeightTraining/WorkoutLogs.html) there are some nice spreadsheet logs ready to use.

In any case, whatever solution you find, I would like to know about it (specially any Linux program) so I encourage you to post it as a comment, for instance.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at those apps, though I'd really like it better online. I've used MapMyRide.com before and loved that, as it tracked progress, and I'd like something similar for strength exercises.

Comment: @DarkLightA one site I use for tracking overall fitness effort is [Fitocracy](http://ftcy.me/KQK4Z7) (web, iPhone, android). There is one site dedicated only to strength but I can't remember the name.

Comment: Might be better to talk about these subjective topics in [chat].